# Nice syntax to get sized reference to vector's/array's data?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, casting

I'm wondering if there's any std:: function to get a sized pointer/reference to a vector/array's underlying data?  Something better than:

```
const size_t(&asArray1)[N] = *(size_t(*)[N]) vec.data();
const size_t(&asArray2)[arr.size()] = *(size_t(*)[arr.size()]) arr.data();
```

Clarification - something I could pass to the below:

```
template<size_t N>
void foo(size_t(&sizedArray)[N]) {}
```

Update -- SOLUTION:
Use helper functions defined once, that do the appropriate casting and leave the call-site cleaner... See my answer below for helper code.

Live demo: https://onlinegdb.com/S167RI20U

Comment: I don't think this is possible due to strict aliasing violation even if `vec.size()` were known at compile time.

Comment: IMHO this cannot work, because the size of the vector is not a compile time constant. And OP is requesting a reference to an array with a compile time constant size.

Comment: You're right Armin, the way I had it typed up.  Getting sloppy late in the night; see above edit.

Comment: The C++ type system is not able to express such type.

Comment: pronouns - `const size_t(&asArray2)[arr.size()] = *(size_t(*)[arr.size()]) vec.data();` compiles fine, it's just ugly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: Use helper functions defined once, that do the appropriate casting and leave the call-site cleaner...  I'm surprised that helpers like these aren't available at least for `std::array`...

For `vector`s, I will admit that it's a rare use case where you have a compile-time known size for the vector. but I do have a use case where I know my vector contains at least as many elements as an array, and I want the first N of them to be processed through some algorithm.  I can guarantee that that many elements are available, and include asserts to boot, etc...

Live demo: https://onlinegdb.com/S167RI20U

```
template<size_t N, typename T>
using CArrayPtr = T(*)[N];

template<size_t N, typename T>
auto& cArray(array<T, N>& arr) {
    return *(CArrayPtr<N, T>)arr.data();
}

template<size_t N, typename T>
auto& cArray(vector<T>& vec) {
    return *(CArrayPtr<N, T>)vec.data();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking for is to decide a type (which must be done at compile time) with information only available at runtime.  It is impossible.

Comment: For the vector case, the assumption is that N is a constexpr known "from some other way."  For the array case, size() is a `constexpr` function, so that isn't true.

Answer (score 2):

C++20 `std::span` encapsulates ugly syntax in its own non-explicit constructor, so just pass it.

Before C++20, there's `std::begin` , `std::end`,  `std::size`, which are not exactly what you need, but may help.

All this is implementable in old compiler, it does not require any special compiler support.

Comment: Well `std::span` has some nice uses, but in my case I want to be able to later use N in `constexpr` contexts, so I don't think `span` will allow that.

Comment: `std::span` can take size as template argument, should be able to pass it and deduce it. Is it still not useful?

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed that, I'm used to the `absl::span` which doesn't have that.  Thanks; I'll give it a try (currently only using a C++17 compiler - no `std::span`, but hopefully soon!)